# NSWorkspace runningApplications doesn't return my XPC mach service

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xpc, mach, nsxpcconnection

```
NSArray *activeApps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
```

Returns running applications and agents, but i cannot see my running XPC mach service (although it is running and visible in activity monitor processes)

even when i look up the PID in activity monitor

```
id res = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:223];
```

i get res nil, although with other processes this works well

Answer (score 0):

The [NSRunningApplication documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRunningApplication) states:

> Only user applications are tracked; this does not provide information
>   about every process on the system

What exactly you trying to accomplish? you dont need to check for a service in this way.

Comment: ok, but what exactly "user applications" means? as this xpc is run by the current user and also helpers without UI are listed... i need to know, it the XPC is running, as from the connection i cannot determine (the response for not running and denied connection is the same)

Comment: User applications mean processes running as that user. Based on what you've described it's likely the code you're trying to monitor is running as root.